# Change password of Azure VM using PowerShell

Tags: azure, powershell, automation

I have tried this approach to change a password of an Azure VM:

```
$resgroup = "rsource1"
$vmName = "virtualmachine1"

$VM = Get-AzVM -ResourceGroupName $resgroup -Name $vmName 

$Credential = Get-Credential

$VM | Set-AzureVMAccessExtension    –UserName $Credential.UserName `
                                    –Password $Credential.GetNetworkCredential().Password

$VM | Update-AzVM
```

But I keep getting this error:

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

When I `console.log` the values of `$Credential.UserName` and `$Credential.GetNetworkCredential().Password` I got the values of *username* and *password* that I have inputted.

What am I missing here?

Comment: See this article. May be useful: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/troubleshooting/reset-rdp#reset-the-local-administrator-account-password-1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've never used `Set-AzureVMAccessExtension`, but I've used the Az PowerShell equivalant [`Set-AzVMAccessExtension`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.compute/set-azvmaccessextension?view=azps-3.6.1). It needs you to pass `-Credential $Credential` instead of -`UserName` and `-Password`.

You can try this script I made a while ago to to reset passwords for Azure VMs:

```
# Replace these values with your own
$resourceGroupName = "Servers-RG"
$vmName = "server1"

# Get the VM into an object
$vm = Get-AzVM -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName -Name $vmName 

# Store credentials you want to change
$credential = Get-Credential -Message "Enter your username and password for $vmName"

# Store parameters in a hashtable for splatting
# Have a look at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_splatting?view=powershell-7
$extensionParams = @{
    'VMName' = $vmName
    'Credential' = $credential
    'ResourceGroupName' = $resourceGroupName
    'Name' = 'AdminPasswordReset'
    'Location' = $vm.Location
}

# Pass splatted parameters and update password
Set-AzVMAccessExtension @extensionParams

# Restart VM
# Don't need to pass any switches since they are inferred ByPropertyName
# Have a look at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_pipelines?view=powershell-7
$vm | Restart-AzVM
```

I found that the password update doesn't happen until you restart the VM, so `Restart-VM` is required.

Comment: This is working for rdp administrator logins only right? Can I know the process of reset the rdp password for general user accounts?

Answer (score 1):

If anyone interested in the Linux (KISS) version (no VM restart needed):

```
$settings = '{}'
$protectedSettings = '{
   "username": "<yourusername, prefer using Credentials object>",
   "password": "<yourpassword, prefer using Credentials object>"
}'        

Set-AzVMExtension `
    -VMName $vmName `
    -ResourceGroupName $rgName `
    -Location $location  `
    -Name "VMAccessForLinux"  `
    -Publisher "Microsoft.OSTCExtensions" `
    -ExtensionType "VMAccessForLinux"  `
    -TypeHandlerVersion "1.4"  `
    -Settingstring $settings `
    -ProtectedSettingString $protectedSettings
```

Comment: Isn't this going to modify other properties? Possible to use `Get-AzVMExtension` before?